# in my eclipse its showing red cross error on each project.how to fix it?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I removed tomcat server after going into windows-->preferences-->server-->run time environments[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BvQ7.png). after this its showing red cross on each project .and not running any project even after adding the server. but newly created projects are running without any error. how to fix this red cross error from every project

Comment: Please show the existing import statement for `WebServlet` and what you have in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ in the _Libraries_ tab. Your Eclipse is pretty outdated and there are two _JRE System Librarry_ nodes instead of one in the project tree.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @howlger, you should clean up your project's Java Build Path so that you only build against one Java runtime.

Ok, so after removing that Tomcat Server Runtime, you were probably prompted to remove it from any projects that were referring to it. If so, this is how to get things working again.

When working with Java, you need a Java Runtime from which to get the classes to compile your own code against. When working with servlets and JSP files, you need to get the Servlet API from somewhere so you can compile against them, and WTP (which you're using) has you get them from an actual server--like Tomcat (ideally the same version of the server you're going to deploy to, so you have the same libraries and classes at development time that you have at runtime). By removing it from your preferences and project(s), they no longer have jar files with those classes to compile your own sources against, so the Java tools don't know what those types are.

That means that fixing the problem requires getting a server runtime back on the Java Build Path. Screenshots are valid for Eclipse IDE 2021-12 (WTP 3.24).

1. Make sure you have a valid runtime on the **Server / Runtime Environments** preference page. In this picture, I've let it download both Apache Tomcat 9 and 10 for me. Really, you **must** have something here to proceed.

[image: The Server Runtime Environment preference page, after downloading Tomcat 9 and 10.]

2. Open the **Java Build Path** property page of your project and select the **Classpath** node. Unless you select that node, the buttons to Add a Library won't enable.

[image: The Property page with the right node selected. The Add Library button enables.]

3. Select the **Server Runtime** type of Library from the list. Continue through the later pages in the dialog until you've selected the runtime you intended. Once finished, your Servlets will be recompiled the next time a build happens.

[image: The Add Library page, showing a variety of library types.]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. To solve this issue just right click on project name and go to properties and then click on project facets. After that, click on runtimes and tick on Apache tomcat and and JRE and then apply. Done.

[image]